# How to do postgresql select query funciton using parameter?

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a postgresql funciton that returns records. But if I pass an id parameter, it should be add in where clause.  if I do not pass or null id parameter, where clasuse will not add the query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(id integer)
RETURNS TABLE (type varchar, total bigint) AS $$
    DECLARE where_clause VARCHAR(200);
BEGIN
    IF id IS NOT NULL THEN
        where_clause = ' group_id= ' || id;
    END IF ;

    RETURN QUERY SELECT
               type,
               count(*) AS total
         FROM                
                table1
         WHERE
               where_clause ???               
         GROUP BY
                   type
         ORDER BY
                   type;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use one condition that takes care of both situations (then you don't need PL/pgSQL to begin with):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(p_id integer)
  RETURNS TABLE (type varchar, total bigint) 
AS $$
SELECT type,
       count(*) AS total
FROM table1
WHERE p_id is null or group_id = p_id
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY type;
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

But an `OR` condition like that is typically not really good for performance. The second option you have, is to simply run two different statements:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(p_id integer)
  RETURNS TABLE (type varchar, total bigint) 
AS $$
begin
  if (p_id is null) then 
    return query      
      SELECT type,
             count(*) AS total
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY type
      ORDER BY type;
  else 
    return query      
      SELECT type,
             count(*) AS total
      FROM table1
      WHERE group_id = p_id
      GROUP BY type
      ORDER BY type;
  end if;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plgpsql;
```

And finally you can build a dynamic SQL string depending the parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(p_id integer)
  RETURNS TABLE (type varchar, total bigint) 
AS $$
declare
  l_sql text;
begin

  l_sql := 'SELECT type, count(*) AS total FROM table1 '
  if (p_id is not null) then 
    l_sql := l_sql || ' WHERE group_id = '||p_id;
  end if;
  l_sql := l_sql || ' GROUP BY type ORDER BY type';

  return query execute l_sql;
end;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is required just to use the variable as it is for more info please refer :[plpgsql function parameters](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-function-parameters/)